# Overriding a django model default value in the default form?

Tags: django, forms, overriding, default

I have a model that looks something like:

```
class DooDad(models.Model):
    doo_dad_dogue = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Trouble is, that default needs to be manipulated by... stuff that is irrelevant to this question. If I were creating the form that creates the object, the solution would be trivial. **I'm still using the django default form for creating these things, though, and I'd rather keep it that way.**

I tried the obvious:

```
class DooDad(models.Model):
    doo_dad_dogue = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DooDad, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.doo_dad_dogue = False
```

...which I suspect would have terrible side effects, but was worth experimenting with. The form still comes up with the box checked.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that this is Django 1.9

**If it is not possible to continue using the default model creation form, is there anything unusual that I need to do to to make a ModelForm that only impacts CREATE, and not EDIT?**

Answer (score 0):

I do not think using the __init__in model is a good practice. However, if you want to try it is important to know that your code is not correct one the field doo_dad_dogue is a descriptor. The correct way to access it is 
using `self.fields['doo_dad_dogue'] = False`.

Using a form is the correct way to do that. You can override the default value in the Form by using the **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(<YOUR_FORM>, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if args is not None and len(args) and args[0] is not None: 
        <MANIPULATE HERE>
```

Hope that helps.